# How to distinguish between empty argument and zero-value argument in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, null, zero

I want to be able to pass a single int through to a powershell script, and be able to tell when no variable is passed.  My understanding was that the following should identify whether an argument is null or not:

```
if (!$args[0]) { Write-Host "Null" }
else { Write-Host "Not null" }
```

This works fine until I try to pass 0 as an int.  If I use 0 as an argument, Powershell treats it as null.  Whats the correct way to be able to distinguish between the argument being empty or having a zero value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just test `$args` variable or `$args.count` to see how many vars are passed to the script.

Another thing `$args[0] -eq $null` is different from  `$args[0] -eq 0` and from `!$args[0]`.

Comment: Didn't realise there was a difference between `$args[0] -eq $null` and `!$args[0]` - many thanks!

Comment: If you use the $Var directly in a condition it evaluates everything that is $Null or 0 to $False.. everything else to $True. So If(-1) is always False.

Comment: @MichaelKargl What do you mean by "if(-1) is always false"? `-1` evaluates to `True` (try `[bool]-1`).  Also note that in addition to `$null` and `0`, empty strings also evaluate to `False` (`[bool]""`)

Comment: My bad.. typo.. its always $True as it is unequal 0.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it explained the differences between the equality checks.  As it is I hear they are different, but I have no idea why.  It should tell me how to properly check for empty/null/zero arguments.

Answer (score 5):

If users like me come from Google and want to know how to treat empty command line parameters, here is a possible solution:

```
if (!$args) { Write-Host "Null" }
```

This checks the $args array. If you want to check the first element of the array (i.e. the first cmdline parameter), use the solution from the OP:

```
if (!$args[0]) { Write-Host "Null" }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is declared in `param()` as an integer then its value will be '0' even if no value is specified for the argument.  To prevent that you have to declare it as nullable:

```
param([AllowNull()][System.Nullable[int]]$Variable)
```

This will allow you to validate with `If ($Variable -eq $null) {}`